# How to set analogue OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions (Microsoft.Owin.Security) in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

I have an application that secured by Microsoft.Owin.Security on .Net Framework. Parameters of generating tokens such as AccessTokenFormat, AccessTokenProvider keeped in OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions class. Protecting of tokens realized in TicketFormatProvider : ISecureDataFormat and its a custom realization for protecting token. I need to migrate to ASP.NET Core and I didn't find an analogue for this methods.
I found Events in services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth middleware for creating and receiving tokens, but can't find protecting tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddJwtBearer` middleware where `TokenValidationParameters` configuration should be used for validating tokens. More about it you can read [here.](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide)